# Cannot run Maven command

Tags: java, maven, terminal, maven-2, war

I am not a professional programmer.i am getting this error when running "mvn clean install". If anyone can explain me to correct this error that would be great.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building erp-web Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/server/Desktop/Hospital project/Healthcare/Source/erp-web/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.erp -DartifactId=erp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.erp -DartifactId=erp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.erp:erp-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.erp:erp-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Here is my POM file content.. I copy paste this from my POM.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.erp</groupId>
    <artifactId>erp-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>erp-web Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Backend API project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.erp</groupId>
            <artifactId>erp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
            Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>mycode</finalName>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: can you attach your pom file? it looks like some dependecies are missing, what plugins are you using?

Comment: Probably the erp jar module is not in the Maven project's dependency management, so the war module cannot resolve it currently.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.. I have copy paste my POM files content please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your artifact `com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT` is not found on all registered repositories. Thus, register an additional repository - if there is already any - that is serving your JARs.

If there is no repository yet serving your libs, then use one of the following solutions:

- Install your libs in a *local* repository as stated in the Maven comment above: `mvn install:install-file ...`. Please find more information about `install:install-file` [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html).
- Use (or first install) a company wide *remote* repository such as [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) and put your JARs to it as also stated in the Maven comment above using following command: `mvn deploy:deploy-file ...`. Please find more information about `deploy:deploy-file` [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

Find some more information about repositories on the [Maven website](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).