# Can i download maven missing artifacts externally from web?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

There is this missing artifact that I need to install.Can I get it from web?*If so please give me a link.*

```
`Missing:
----------
1) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.erp -DartifactId=erp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.erp -DartifactId=erp -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) com.erp:erp-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2) com.erp:erp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  com.erp:erp-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`
```

Comment: try http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run Maven command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930907/cannot-run-maven-command)

Comment: This is basically the same question as one that you have previously asked (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21930907/1570834). I presume that the com.erp:erp:jar project is one you are also creating. You should build that project first (maven will then install the resultant jar in your local repository), and then build the com.erp:erp-web:war project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you know which component you need. com.erp:erp-web is not in Maven Central. Maybe you're missing a repository block in your pom.xml file? Since it's a WAR file, I'm not quite sure what kind of dependency you think you can use it as? What are you trying to accomplish?